# ACF - Wrapper Attributes

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've created a field using Advanced Custom Fields, and have assigned a class to the Wrapper Attributes. However I have yet to find out any method/documentation how exactly to get ahold of this information (how to get the class).

I've used get_field in order to get all values of the field, but it does not display anything more than the URL really.

```
string(22) "http://www.google.com2"
```

I've tried with the following also after using get_field

```
echo $test['class'];
```

Which then only provides back the letter h for some reason in this case:

```
hstring(22) "http://www.google.com2"
```

Code:

```
<?php the_field('learn_more_url_-_section_1'); ?>
<?php
    $test = get_field('learn_more_url_-_section_1');

    echo $test['class'];

    var_dump($test);

?>
```

Here is a screenshot of the field setup:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrapper attributes are specific to the backend display of the fields/field group. You would use an admin CSS file to optimize the backend display using whatever class you entered.